# Linux Mdadm + LVM recovery

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mdadm, lvm

I recently reinstalled my Ubuntu server with 10.04, and am having trouble reactivating the LVM partition which houses all my non-critical data. `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc`, and `/dev/sdd` are all assembled into a Raid-5 array `/dev/md0`, upon which sits a single VG `media` with LG `part1` (I think; I used to be able to manually mount it with `vgchange -ay media && mount /dev/mapper/media-part1`). My issue is currently, I cannot get the system to detect the VG and activate it. Not 20 minutes ago I had it working just fine (I had encountered this issue on the previous startup, but failed to write down what steps I took to actually get the VG activated when I last booted the system).

The raid assembles just fine and is clean, but I cannot get the VG to show up or mount. `pvck /dev/md0` displays:
`Device /dev/md0 not found (or ignored by filtering).`
The filter in my `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` is `filter = [ "a/.*/" ]`

`pvck /dev/md0p1` displays:
`Could not find LVM label on /dev/md0p1`

`pvdisplay` produces the following output:

> ```
>  Setting global/locking_type to 1
>   Setting global/wait_for_locks to 1
>   File-based locking selected.
>   Setting global/locking_dir to /var/lock/lvm
>   Locking /var/lock/lvm/P_global RB
> Scanning for physical volume names
>   /dev/ram0: No label detected
>   /dev/md0p1: Label for sector 1 found at sector 0 - ignoring
>   /dev/md0p1: No label detected
>   /dev/ram1: No label detected
>   /dev/sda1: Label for sector 1 found at sector 0 - ignoring
>   /dev/sda1: No label detected
>   /dev/ram2: No label detected
>   /dev/ram3: No label detected
>   /dev/ram4: No label detected
>   /dev/ram5: No label detected
>   /dev/ram6: No label detected
>   /dev/ram7: No label detected
>   /dev/ram8: No label detected
>   /dev/ram9: No label detected
>   /dev/ram10: No label detected
>   /dev/ram11: No label detected
>   /dev/ram12: No label detected
>   /dev/ram13: No label detected
>   /dev/ram14: No label detected
>   /dev/ram15: No label detected
>   /dev/sdb1: No label detected
>   /dev/sde1: No label detected
>   /dev/sdf1: No label detected
>   /dev/sdg1: No label detected
>   /dev/sdh1: No label detected
>   /dev/sdi1: No label detected
>   /dev/root: No label detected
>   /dev/sdj3: No label detected
>   /dev/sdj4: No label detected
>   /dev/sdj5: No label detected
>   /dev/sdj6: No label detected
>   Unlocking /var/lock/lvm/P_global
> ```

`/dev/m0p1` is where the PV should be stored, but it's not showing up. Sadly, I do not have my `/etc/lvm/backup` directory from my previous installation.

I'm pretty sure the data is all there, I just need to know
a) **How can I force lvm to search the `/dev/md0` device for the volume group, and**
b) **How can I fix this so that the system will detect and activate the volume group on startup** (the RAID array already assembles on startup).

I'm not sure I fully understand how exactly the LVM sits upon the physical devices, so if I seem confused in my terminology, please correct it. (PVs are physical devices, a VG sits atop one or more PVs, and there are one or more LV in a VG, somewhat like partitions in a conventional harddisk?)

My current lvm.conf (as provided by `lvm dumpconf`) is:

> ```
>  devices {
>     dir="/dev"
>     scan="/dev/disk"
>     preferred_names=[]
>     filter="a/.*/"
>     cache_dir="/etc/lvm/cache"
>     cache_file_prefix=""
>     write_cache_state=1
>     sysfs_scan=1
>     md_component_detection=1
>     md_chunk_alignment=1
>     data_alignment_detection=1
>     data_alignment=0
>     data_alignment_offset_detection=1
>     ignore_suspended_devices=0
>   }
>   dmeventd {
>     mirror_library="libdevmapper-event-lvm2mirror.so"
>     snapshot_library="libdevmapper-event-lvm2snapshot.so"
>   }
>   activation {
>     udev_sync=1
>     missing_stripe_filler="error"
>     reserved_stack=256
>     reserved_memory=8192
>     process_priority=-18
>     mirror_region_size=512
>     readahead="auto"
>     mirror_log_fault_policy="allocate"
>     mirror_device_fault_policy="remove"
>   }
>   global {
>     umask=63
>     test=0
>     units="h"
>     si_unit_consistency=1
>     activation=1
>     proc="/proc"
>     locking_type=1
>     wait_for_locks=1
>     fallback_to_clustered_locking=1
>     fallback_to_local_locking=1
>     locking_dir="/var/lock/lvm"
>     prioritise_write_locks=1
>   }
>   shell {
>     history_size=100
>   }
>   backup {
>     backup=1
>     backup_dir="/etc/lvm/backup"
>     archive=1
>     archive_dir="/etc/lvm/archive"
>     retain_min=10
>     retain_days=30
>   }
>   log {
>     verbose=0
>     syslog=1
>     overwrite=0
>     level=0
>     indent=1
>     command_names=0
>     prefix="  "
>   }
> ```

EDIT:
It seems the LVM refuses to scan the MD devices.

> ```
> dandroid@tinuvael:/etc/lvm$ sudo vgcfgrestore --test --verbose media
>  Test mode: Metadata will NOT be updated.
>  Wiping cache of LVM-capable devices
>  Couldn't find device with uuid 'iTmyql-LYQv-N1GD-6aM0-BHco-uHEe-taHhBI'.
>  Cannot restore Volume Group media with 1 PVs marked as missing.
>  Restore failed.
>  Test mode: Wiping internal cache
>  Wiping internal VG cache
> ```
>
> `dandroid@tinuvael:/etc/lvm$ sudo blkid`
>   **`/dev/md0: UUID="iTmyql-LYQv-N1GD-6aM0-BHco-uHEe-taHhBI" TYPE="LVM2_member"`** 
>   `/dev/sdc: UUID="b81c877f-6542-d03b-4e08-ceb6032f5cfe" TYPE="linux_raid_member"` 
>   `/dev/sdd: UUID="b81c877f-6542-d03b-4e08-ceb6032f5cfe" TYPE="linux_raid_member"`

I have trimmed several irrelevant lines, but the above shows that the raid array is mounted and has the UUID that LVM is searching for, but it still continues to ignore the device after adding `types = [ "md", 16 ]` to my configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the drives had partition tables added to them (probably when I was mucking around and trying to get the BIOS to boot the right drive on startup), and LVM absolutely refuses to look at a device which contains a partition table. After blanking the partition table with `fdisk`, LVM detected the volume group perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer. How exactly did you blank the partition table? I'm a little confused seeing as how I run lvm on partitioned devices all the time. Did your raid array have partitions INSIDE itself?

Comment: Whether good or bad practice, I raid the devices, not partitions, and my LVM volumes are on the devices, not partitions (i.e., `pvcreate /dev/md0`) In my attempts to make the system boot without user help, I installed grub to one of the phsyical devices, but this causes the partition table to show up in the raid device (i.e., `/dev/md0p1`, though it was corrupt - The actual raid data was fine). Because the raid device had a partition table now, LVM refused to search `/dev/md0` and would only search `/dev/md0p1`.  I told fdisk to create a new partition table and wrote it to disk to blank it.